# Check if object is equal but compare only keys that defined in both objects

Tags: java, hashmap

i have this situation:

```
Map<String, Object> origin = new HashMap<String, Object>();
origin.put("name", "client");
origin.put("website", "https://google.com");
origin.put("settings", new HashMap<String, Object>());

Map<String, Object> other = new HashMap<String, Object>();
other.put("id", "client");
other.put("name", "client");
other.put("website", "https://google.com");
other.put("settings", new HashMap<String, Object>());


if(Objects.equals(origin, other)) {
  System.out.println("TRUE");
} else {
  System.out.println("FALSE");
}
```

The result is false, because `origin` does not contain `id`.

`origin` is always a subset of `other`. Both Map can contains nested maps and lists.

Is there a smart java operation which checks if the values in `origin` are the same in `other` and give true back? Or do I had to iterate through the maps and compare each key?

Comment: You have to do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like : *is `origin` is a submap of `other`*, verifying that all mappings from `origin` are in `other` but you have missing items but don't care.

So fo each key of `origin` check if values are same in both `Maps`

```
boolean subMap = origin.keySet().stream().allMatch(key -> origin.get(key).equals(other.get(key)));

if (subMap) {
    System.out.println("TRUE");
} else {
    System.out.println("FALSE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
boolean result = origin.keySet().stream()
    .allMatch(key -> !other.containsKey(key) || origin.get(key).equals(other.get(key)));
```